# Related list update on Parent Account

Tags: apex, trigger

Here is a trigger based on scenario:
opportunity: primary competitor(text) and primary machine(text)
competitor: name,primary competitor(check box), primary Machine(text)

opp ,comp having relationship.
Trigger: on comp: if pc==true - > it has to capture the competitor name , primary machine values on the  opportunity fields(pc,pm).

below trigger works fine accordingly .But 
Problem: for the first time when the pc==true ,it captured the values but if i uncheck the pc of if i delete the pc,then it has to remove the previous values from opp.need help.

here is my work

```
public with sharing class CompetitorTriggerHandler {

  // update the primary competitor,Primary Machine when new records are inserted from trigger
  public void OnAfterInsert(List<Competitor__c> newRecords){
    updatePrimaryCompetitor(newRecords); 
   //updatePrimaryCompetitorMachine(newRecords); 
  }

  // update the primary competitor primary Machine when records are updated from trigger  
  public void OnAfterUpdate(List<Competitor__c> oldRecords, 
      List<Competitor__C> updatedRecords,  Map<ID,Competitor__C> oldMap, 
      Map<ID,Competitor__C> newMap){
      updatePrimaryCompetitor(updatedRecords); 
  // updatePrimaryCompetitorMachine(updatedRecords); 

  }

  // updates the opportunity with the primary competitor and primary competitor Machine 
  private void updatePrimaryCompetitor(List<Competitor__C> newRecords) {

    // create a new map to hold the opportunity id / competitor values
    Map<ID,String> OpportunityCompetitorMap = new Map<ID,String>();
  Map<ID,String> OpportunityCompetitorMachineMap = new Map<ID,String>();
    // if an competitor is marked as primary, 
    // to the map where the opportunity id is the key 
    for (Competitor__c com : newRecords) {
      if (com.Primary_Competitor__c)
      {
        OpportunityCompetitorMap.put(com.Opportunity__c,com.Competitor_Name__c);
        OpportunityCompetitorMachineMap.put(com.Opportunity__c,com.Competitor_Machine__c);
      } }


    // query for the opportunity in the context to update
    List<Opportunity> orders = [select id, Primary_Competitor__c,Primary_Competitor_Machine__c from Opportunity where id IN:  OpportunityCompetitorMap.keyset()];


    // add the primary country to the sales order. find it in the map
    // using the Opportunities's id as the key
    for (Opportunity so : orders)
    {
      so.Primary_Competitor__c = OpportunityCompetitorMap.get(so.id);
  so.Primary_Competitor_Machine__c = OpportunityCompetitorMachineMap.get(so.id);
    // commit the records 
    update orders;
    }
  }
}
```

trigger:

```
trigger trigComp on Competitor__c(before update, after insert, after update) {
    if (trigger.isbefore) {
        ctrlCompetitor cc = new ctrlCompetitor();
        cc.onUpdatePrimaryComp();
    }
    if (trigger.isafter) {
        CompetitorTriggerHandler handler = new CompetitorTriggerHandler();
        if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
            handler.OnAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
        } else if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) {
            handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to revert to the values before that checkbox was checked.

So you could query the OpportunityHistory object to get back the previous values, provided you track history on those fields.
Also to add, you could check the Trigger.old and Trigger.new values to identify the changed status of the checkbox.

Comment: :here is the trigger   trigger trigComp on Competitor__c (before update,after insert, after update) {
if(trigger.isbefore)
{
    ctrlCompetitor cc=new ctrlCompetitor();
    cc.onUpdatePrimaryComp();
    }
    
  if(trigger.isafter) {

  CompetitorTriggerHandler handler = new  CompetitorTriggerHandler();
    
  if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
    handler.OnAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
    
  } else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) { 
    handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
    
  }

}
    
}

Comment: You could check in your OnAfterUpdate method the changes to your Primary_competitor__c field and decide whether to perform an update or rollback the values. Like mentioned before, you can query the OpportunityHistory to get the previous values if any.

Comment: i'm not sure about the process how to put into code

Comment: something like this to check for change of field in your OnAfterUpdate method: oldMap.get(competitorId).Primary_Competitor__c != newMap.get(competitorId).Primary_Competitor__c

Comment: any idea about database rollback

Comment: Well you do have the setSavePoint and rollback system methods, but I dont think it might quite suit your case, since its going to be in different transactions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12727/discussion-between-user4902-and-aslamk)